# CAST variable to FLOAT without operation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to cast variable without computation?

Like this:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(interestRate, PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', interestRate + ' '), LEN(interestRate)) AS FLOAT Interest_Rate
```

Because I keep getting errors. But if my column is like this:

```
((CAST(SUBSTRING(interestRate, PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', interestRate + ' '), LEN(interestRate)) AS FLOAT) /100)/12) monthlyInterestRate
```

I do not get any error. Can someone explain? Newbie here.

Comment: "I keep getting errors" It would be helpful to specify which error do you get? Currently there's a missing ")" after FLOAT.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
((SUBSTRING(interestRate, PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', interestRate + ' '), LEN(interestRate)) /100.0)/12.0) monthlyInterestRate
```

notice that addin  `.0` implicit convert to float operation. Otherwise all integer numbers will truncate decimals

Comment: I think you copied the same I have. My question is, "Is it possible to cast variable without computation?"

Comment: @MichelleRigor look carfully `/100.0)/12.0)`

Comment: @MichelleRigor I forget to remove cast to float, sorry, corrected

Comment: @MichelleRigor Letme know how is was. Do you know how to accept an answer? if not, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/tour